# Is the angle between two vectors always between $0$ and $\pi$?

Tags: vectors

My friend's physics book (specifically, a [physics coaching module for engineering entrance exams](http://www.dlpd.resonance.ac.in/Downloads/Sample-Study-Material/2020/NEET-Physics.pdf)) stated that the angle $\theta$ between two vectors is always $ 0 \leq \theta \leq \pi $ :
[image]
I feel this is incorrect because then the angle between $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ would be the same as the angle between $-\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$, and it would make more sense if the statement was either  $ -\pi \leq \theta \leq \pi $ or  $ 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi $.

Is the book correct? If not, what is the correct range of the angle between two vectors?

Comment: I think you are interpreting the definition incorrectly: the angle between $A$ and $B$ is not the same as the angle between $-A$ and $B$ with that definition. For instance, in the leftmost picture the angle between $A$ and $B$ is about $\pi/4$, while the angle between $-A$ and $B$ is about $3\pi/4$.

Comment: A definition stated in a book is only valid within the book. It may be a more widely accepted convention but in general there is a level of arbitrariness to it. You should expect another book to have its own definitions which woud not necessarily be compatible with yours. Definitions are meant to be usefull rather than state philosophical truths.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It depends on how you define the word "between".

By *the angle between two vectors* we typically mean the smallest angle. Which will always be within half a round.

Comment: +1 To emphasize, it is a *convention*, not a mathematical truth.

Comment: Thank you! I think I mixed up the angle between two vectors with it's direction.

Comment: The other half of the question is why this convention is more useful than the opposite one. Do you have good motivations to suggest?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni I don't see another half of the question. But regarding the motivation, we typically want our definitions of properties to be shortest/simplest possible for what is necessarily for a unique definition. In this case, two angles uniquely define the relative orientation of two vectors, so why not pick the smaller one. Also, this happens to fit well with our intuitive and colloquial use "between".

Comment: "typically always" is an interesting modifier.  It's my *impression* that there is no standard definition of the angle.  I would say that whomever is writing needs to define what he or she means, as the book's author has done.  One disadvantage of this definition is the confusion that can result from things like  $W=|F|\,|d|\cos\theta$

Comment: @garyp That's a good point. The interesting modifier  "typically always" has now been shortened to a not-as-interesting "typically".